# GitHub Markdown NodeJS (`ghm`)

Tags: node.js, github

I am using https://github.com/thomblake/github-flavored-markdown. Works but when I delimit code like:

````
```javascript
some code here ...
```
````

Theres no syntax hilighting, do I need to include something? Like CSS or something? I could use another library of course, but that will defeat the purpose of the ```` ```javascript ```` part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It certainly looks like the `pygments.css` file in the distribution under `shared/css/` is necessary for syntax highlighting to be displayed. Assuming you're serving the results to a browser, you should probably be serving all of `shared` as static files.